# League\Flysystem\Filesystem::delete(): Argument #1 ($location) must be of type string, null given, called in

Tags: php, laravel, edit, photo

i can't edit photo

php version  8.1.4

laravel 9.14.1

update function :

```
 public function update(Request $request, Category $category)
{
    $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required'
    ]);

    $image = $category->image;
    if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
        Storage::delete($category->$image);
        $image = $request->file('image')->store('public/categories');
    }
    $category->update([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'description' => $request->description,
        'image' => $image
    ]);

    return to_route('admin.categories.index');
}
```

error :

League\Flysystem\Filesystem::delete(): Argument #1 ($location) must be of type string, null given, called in C:\Users\sedat\Desktop\newproject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemAdapter.php on line 481

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try:

```
!is_null($category->image) && Storage::delete($category->image);
```

Comment: this worked . so is there any other way? such as package, update, add

Comment: you should never touch package source code